# PFQuery result combine

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am creating backend with parse and have 2 different class like this. owner_id in Item is same as Object id in Profile. I retrieve required items like this. After I retrieve, I will have owner_id. I can retrieve with separate query from Profile to get username. However, I want to show those data at the same time and I plan to merge/combine two separate query. May I know how to do?

```
PFQuery *detailQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Item"];
[detailQuery whereKey:SERVER_OBJECT_ID containedIn:muArr];
[detailQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        self.mainData = @{SERVER_RESULT: objects};
        [self getListResult:self.mainData];
    }
}];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can create a new query inside a different query if they are two different classes. However, the more efficient method in this case would be to use relations or pointers. It's the more sane route I think, but ultimately get your desired result, populate at the same time. Look at parses docs on relations

Comment: Thanks. I plan to use pointer also. However, problem is that I want to get my retrieved data in 1 shot. For example, I want to get Item_name from Item, username from Profile at the same time.  Currently, I only store owner_id and I will need to search back username from Profile.

Comment: Yes you can do it all at the same time with pointers/relations